# When implementing a statement-level trigger on a table, is it possible to obtain the OLD and NEW records for all affected rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

In Oracle, you can write a row-level trigger by specifying the `FOR EACH ROW` clause in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MY_FANCY_TRIGGER
  BEFORE UPDATE ON MY_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.my_id_column > 4 AND :NEW.some_other_column <> 'foo' THEN
    -- ...
  END IF;
END;
```

Such a trigger allows you to view the *before* and *after* versions of each affected row (`:OLD` and `:NEW` respectively). For example, the following statement will cause this trigger to execute once for each row in `MY_TABLE`:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET some_other_column = 'bar';
```

By eliminating the `FOR EACH ROW` clause, the trigger becomes a *statement*-level trigger. This means that it only be executed once *per statement*, regardless of how many rows (if any) were affected by the statement. Unfortunately, statement-level triggers do not have the `:OLD` and `:NEW` variables available (because the number of affected rows many vary).

Is it possible to obtain the `:OLD` and `:NEW` values for *all* affected rows inside a statement-level trigger? I have some processing that I would prefer to only occur once per statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach is the one suggested by Justin Cave to store away information in row level triggers in a separate package collections.

If you are using 11g then the right approach will be to use Compound triggers. This avoids the creation of separate package to hold  the keys collection- it can be done in the trigger itself,

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as the preferred go-forward solution.

Answer (score 8):

Not directly, no.

The standard approach is the "three-trigger solution" (more commonly used when you're trying to work around a mutating table problem)

1. Create a package that contains a collection of keys to your table
2. Create a before statement trigger that initializes the collection
3. Create a row-level trigger that inserts the keys into the collection.
4. Create an after statement trigger that uses the keys in the collection to do its processing

Obviously, in your case, this probably just adds complexity to the process if your row-level trigger isn't causing a mutating table error.

As josephj1989 points out below, if you happen to be using 11g, you can use [compound triggers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFGFD) to simplify this a bit.  You'll still declare a collection, populate the collection in a row-level trigger body, and process the collection in the statement-level trigger.  But there will be just one object to create and manage rather than multiple objects.

Comment: Interesting approach. You're right, it does add complexity, but it may be my only option (10g). Do *statement*-level triggers fire before *row*-level triggers?

Comment: A before-statement trigger fires before a row-level before-insert/ update/ delete trigger.  An after-statement trigger fires after a row-level after-insert/ update/ delete trigger.